# Express combining two directories and changing the path

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

So I'm making an app with nodejs, express, and angularjs. I was following a couple of tutorials and decided to integrate into my project.

I have a `index.html` and there there is a button to create a multi-step form using Angularjs and UI-route. [Form link](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/RQ0yKr)

Then I found a youtube playlist for MEAN Stack, server works fine. As everyone I routed `/public` also.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

**The problem starts here,**

Button in the `index.html` it supposly goes to **/app/views/forms/main-form.html** to create the `ui-view`.

```
<div class="btn">
    <form action="/app/views/forms/main-form.html">
        <input type="submit" value="Get Started" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Before I integrated express into my project, the path was working fine. Somehow, I think something to do with Express, when I click I get the following 404 error.

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/app/views/forms/assets/css/form.css'
 because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and 
 strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

My problem is not about being a MIME type. The original path to CSS is **/assets/css/form.css**, but somehow it takes the `form-main.html` path at the beginning which is **/app/views/forms** also.

It is the same with `formController` as well. The controller normally is in the path of **/app/controllers/formCtrl.js** but the error goes like **/app/views/forms/app/controllers/formCtrl.js**

I would like to know how it takes two directories and combines them and why?

---

**Edit**
After using the CDN of Angularjs instead of local lib, it can get the link directly. But combining two directories is still continue to happening.

Comment: I would consider not using angularjs as it's no longer supported. I would rather use modern angular which is a different thing. Now please show do you link css.

Comment: Due to luck of time, cannot learn Angular in the moment. I link CSS in the main-form.css like this 
``<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/form.css">``
``<script src="/app/controllers/formCtrl.js"></script>``

Comment: Instead of using local lib for angularjs-1.8.2, I used Angularjs CDN and it solved the problem!